# Pandas pivot dataframe where values are a function of two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose we have a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'A_values': [3, 4], 'B': [5, 6],  'B_values': [7, 8]})
```

I want to sort of pivot this dataframe so that we have columns `A` and `B` suffixed with their values as index and column names in a new dataframe (i.e. `index = ['A_1', 'A_2'], columns = ['B_5', 'B_6']`), and the values of this new dataframe would be a result of a function on columns `A_values` and `B_values`. Suppose the function is a simple sum. For `A = 1` we have `A_values = 3`, for `B = 5` we have `B_values = 7`, therefore in the new dataframe at the intersection of `A_1` and `B_5` we would have `3+7=10`. Complete resulting dataframe below:

```
df_pivoted = pd.DataFrame([[3+7, 3+8], [4+7, 4+8]], index = ['A_1', 'A_2'], columns = ['B_5', 'B_6'])
```

After searching for a while I did not find the functionality in `.pivot_table()` that would allow to pass a function of multiple columns as values. Maybe there is a more suitable method for this situation? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do `filter` with index , then `merge`  (which also know as cross join in SQL) with new key and pivot . here I am using `groupby` with `unstack` which is equal to `pivot_table`

```
A=df.filter(like='A').assign(key=1)
B=df.filter(like='B').assign(key=1)
s=A.merge(B)
s=s.assign(value=s.A_values+s.B_values).groupby(['A','B'])['value'].sum().unstack()
s
B   5   6
A        
1  10  11
2  11  12
```